# windows service doesn't stop

Tags: windows, service

I have a problem concerning a windows service that I have implemented. The service does what it has to and logs various information but when I try to stop it, it doesn't seem to stop and keeps logging.

I am not very familiar with services, so if anyone knows why this is happening please tell me.

Edit: I have tested the service on two servers and the weird thing is that on one server it stops normally, but on the other it doesn't. That is what I don't understand.

Comment: what error you are getting? try 'net stop <service_name>' and update the error code. use that error code to get a detailed description of problem using `net helpmsg <error_code>` command.

Answer (score 0):

IN case you have any threads ensure that you exit those threads in your stop routine. Some threads may still be lingering which is why it does not stop.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be because of some remaining thread (as mentioned by 'ckv').

Have you set proper handler using `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` function?
Also make sure that the `SERVICE_STATUS` structure that you use has its `dwControlsAccepted` set to accept `shutdown or stop` (by setting `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN & SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP`). and don't forget to update the service status (using `SetServiceStatus` function) once the service is up and running.